# When using Templates in C++, what does the "T()" function do?

Tags: c++, templates

What does the T() do?  I have been looking for awhile and can't get a definitive answer.

```
    Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T> & v)
{
    my_size = v.my_size;
    my_capacity = v.my_capacity;
    buffer = new T[my_capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < my_size; i++)
        buffer[i] = v.buffer[i];
    for (int i = my_size; i< my_capacity; i++)
        buffer[i] = T();
}
```

Comment: Default constructor of type `T`.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Check the initializations of `i` again. The second loop starts where the first leaves off.

Comment: Better yet use `T{}`.

Comment: BTW, the second loop seems useless as - it is for capacity. - `new T[]` has already do some initialization.

Comment: Hint: if it's a `Vector<MyClass>` then what does `MyClass()` do?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - it's not a default constructor; it's a temporary object initialized with the default constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 It does have some initialization, if `T` is composite type. However, if `T` is merely an `int`, there is no initialization.

Comment: @PeteBecker But, it is a default constructor, of type `T`, call, is it not? It returns a temporary object, yes. This is why I left it as a comment, rather than an answer - I didn't feel like going too in-depth.

Answer (score 8):

`T()` creates an object of type `T` which is value-initialized. For arithmetic and pointer types this means they are zero-initialized, while for class types it means the default constructor is called. You can see more details here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

You can also use this syntax outside templates. For example

```
typedef int T;
T x = T(); // sets x to 0
```